# New to Typescript/Angular. TS2339 compiling error. *ngIf="x.length > 0;" should be false but still tries to compile the elements inside

Tags: html, angular, angularjs, typescript

I'm following a Typescript/Angular course that is showing me how to use "*ngIf". The instructor is giving an example of an empty array so that it fails the condition and compiles the second set of ul tags. It worked for the instructor, but not for me.

image-box.component.html

```
<div id="image-box">
    <div class="left">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1606857521015-7f9fcf423740?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80"/>
        <app-title></app-title>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <h3>Contracts</h3>
        <ul *ngIf="contractInComponent.length > 0">
            <li *ngFor="let contract of contractInComponent">
                Service: {{ contract.service }} <br>
                Title: {{ contract.title }}
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul *ngIf="contractInComponent.length == 0">
            <li>Empty</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

get-data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GetDataService {

  constructor() { }

  getContracts() {
    return [];
  }
}
```

image-box.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
//import { ImageBoxService } from './image-box.service';
import { GetDataService } from './get-data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-image-box',
  templateUrl: './image-box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./image-box.component.scss']
})
export class ImageBoxComponent implements OnInit {
  contractInComponent;
  constructor(service:
    GetDataService) {
    this.contractInComponent = service.getContracts();
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Compiled with problems:

```
ERROR

src/app/image-box/image-box.component.html:12:38 - error TS2339: Property 'service' does not exist on type 'never'.

12                 Service: {{ contract.service }} <br>
                                        ~~~~~~~

  src/app/image-box/image-box.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './image-box.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component ImageBoxComponent.


ERROR

src/app/image-box/image-box.component.html:13:36 - error TS2339: Property 'title' does not exist on type 'never'.

13                 Title: {{ contract.title }}
                                      ~~~~~

  src/app/image-box/image-box.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './image-box.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component ImageBoxComponent.
```

This works when I explicitly use Booleans. The first ul tag gets ignored and compiles the second set. The output is 0.

image-box.component.html

```
<div id="image-box">
    <div class="left">
        <!-- <h2>{{ contractInComponent[0].service }}</h2> -->
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1606857521015-7f9fcf423740?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80"/>
        <app-title></app-title>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <h3>Contracts</h3>
        <ul *ngIf="false">
            <li *ngFor="let contract of contractInComponent">
                Service: {{ contract.service }} <br>
                Title: {{ contract.title }}
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul *ngIf="true">
            <li>{{ contractInComponent.length }}</li> <!-- output = 0 -->
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

get-data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GetDataService {

  constructor() { }

  getContracts() {
    return [];
  }
}
```

Comment: If I had to guess I think your error is because your compiler sees that getContracts never returns an item. Try adding the return type of getContracts explicitly ```getContracts() : any {
    return [];
  }```

Comment: @NathanT. This worked. Can you help explain or point to a good resource?

Comment: the angular docs (angular.io) have a really good introduction course. the docs are well written and if I'm not mistaken they also have video guides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your compiler automatically determines a return type and sees that your **getContracts()**  is always returning undefined. That's why you have the error. If you explicitly add a return type like this.

```
getContracts() : any {
     return [];   
}
```

The error will disappear because you tell the compiler it will potentially return something.

Answer (score 0):

I only get an error due to the fact that you are injecting the dependency GetDataService as service but you are not creating the reference to it (aka missing the private word before the service word)

```
constructor(service:GetDataService){} //causes error
constructor(private service:GetDataService){} //works fine
```

You can see it running in this StackBlitz replication:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tdcxk7?file=src/test/test.component.ts

Comment: if you don't need the service outside your constructor then why should he make it a field of his component? If I remove the private in your stackblitz it still works because it's only used inside the constructor.

Comment: You are right, I just assumed it was outside the constructor, as I rarely use the service that way directly inside it

Comment: I just think he has some really strict compileOptions enabled that give him the error but not in the stackblitz

Comment: Tried it because I was curious. Unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: Probably right, extra typing helps there